# Google API - set OAuth scope

Tags: android, oauth

I´m new to Google APIs and OAuth Authorizations but now I have to set a OAuth scope and after some hours of searching in the web I still dont know how to do it.

I´m working on a Calendar App for Android, reading and creating events for the Google Calendar. At the moment my OAuth scope seems to be Read-Only, so I have to change it to create events. When looking in the Googles Developer Console, I can see an OAuth Authorization, but nothing for change the scope. Where can I set the OAuth scope?

This is the onCreate-method of my MainActivity. I took it from the Google Calendar API Android Quickstart Tutorial. It seems like I already have a OAuth 2.0 Client, referring to https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth . The Scope here is Calender_ReadOnly . When changing it to Calender for read and write access (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/CalendarScopes.html) , my application is not working anymore.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;

GoogleAccountCredential credential;
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));

    mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("TimesheetTest")
            .build();

}
```

Comment: do you want to set up a two legged or three legged OAUTH 2.0?

Comment: @ShivaShinde : I dont want to set up a new OAuth 2.0 Client, I just want to change the scope of the old one.